# Which classes are unmodifiable and cannot be intrumented and is there a way to bypass it?

Tags: java, instrumentation, internals

When trying to instrument classes such as `java.util.ArrayList`, I was getting `java.lang.instrument.UnmodifiableClassException`.

you can check if a class is modifiable using `Instrumentation.isModifiableClass()`.

My question is:

1. Which classes are not modifable? How is it determined.
2. Is there a way to bypass this?

By the way, I didn't get this exception when working with HotSpot or Jrocking, only with IBM JVM.

Thanks,
Gilad

Answer (score 3):

You should call `isModifiableClass` on your instrumentation

```
boolean isModifiableClass(Class<?> theClass)
```

Look [here for the reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#isModifiableClass%28java.lang.Class%29)

> **Determines whether a class is modifiable by retransformation or redefinition. If a class is modifiable then this method returns true. If a class is not modifiable then this method returns false.**
>   For a class to be retransformed, isRetransformClassesSupported() must also be true. But the value of isRetransformClassesSupported() does not influence the value returned by this function. For a class to be redefined, isRedefineClassesSupported() must also be true. But the value of isRedefineClassesSupported() does not influence the value returned by this function.
>
> Primitive classes (for example, java.lang.Integer.TYPE) and array classes are never modifiable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, this is what I'm doing. My question is what determines if a class is unmodifiable, and if there's a way to bypass it...

Comment: I don't see a way to bypass it. I guess that's the way JVM is kept secure, so that you can't modify everyhting.